# Open and read a txt file?

Tags: python

I need to open a txt file with python but I don't know how because the data in the txt is not familiar for me. Next the firsts lines. How can I read theses and then use it?

What is this?

```
[
{
  "complemento": {
    "valorTotal": 24.9
  },
  "dets": [
    {
      "nItem": "1",
      "prod": {
        "indTot": "1",
        "qCom": 1.0,
        "uCom": "UN",
        "vProd": 3.5,
        "vUnCom": 3.5,
        "xProd": "AGUA"
      }
    },
    {
      "nItem": "2",
      "prod": {
        "indTot": "1",
        "qCom": 0.312,
        "uCom": "KG",
        "vProd": 21.4,
        "vUnCom": 68.6,
        "xProd": "BUFFET"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Looks like a json file, are you missing part of the file? It seems cut off

Answer (score 1):

This is a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) file. Importing it using `json.load(path)` will give you a Python `dict` that has the exact same structure you see in your file.

Comment: It's an incomplete JSON file, so `json.load()` won't work unless there's more to it.

Comment: OP stated that these are the first few lines only, so I assumed it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

That is a JSON file but it is not complete. Some part is missing.
You can use JSON LINT http://jsonlint.com/ to validate a json file.
For parsing json in python u can use json library details can be found in this post.
https://dzone.com/articles/python-reading-json-file

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file in python like this:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as your_file:
     content = your_file.read()
```

After this the content of your file will be in the variable `content`.
I would like to answer the rest of your question but I cannot understand it. Srry